# Showing 8 columns together in a cell of a table in Microsoft Report Viewer

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, microsoft-reporting

I have a table which takes show some data in its cells, which comes from a method using a linq query to get the values from database. What i need to do is tto show 8 columns from a table in the database in a cell of table in the cell of the last column in this Report[image]

Is it possible to do that?And if it is, how can i do that?
**Here is the code which returns the values expected by the Report**

```
List<KurBakiyeDegiskenleri> kurToplamlist = new List<KurBakiyeDegiskenleri>();
var query = from kur in kurToplamlist
                       //where kurTL.DovizTuruGetSet == dovizTuru
                       //where kur.KurToplamMiktarGetSet>0
                       join cariBilg in db.TBLP1CARIs
                                     on kur.CariIdGetSet equals cariBilg.ID
                       select new
                       {
                           cariBilg.K_FIRMAADI,//FIRMA ADI
                           cariBilg.K_YETKILIADI,//YETKILI ADI
                           cariBilg.K_FIRMATELEFON,//FIRMA TEL
                           cariBilg.K_YETKILITELEFON,//YETKILI TEL
                           BAKIYE = kur.KurToplamMiktarGetSet,//BAKİYE

                       };
 return query;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static IEnumerable GetBakiyeTumKurlarToplam(DateTime baslangicTarihi, DateTime bitisTarihi) 
        {
            Baglanti();

            List<KurBakiyeDegiskenleri> kurToplamlist = new List<KurBakiyeDegiskenleri>();
            kurToplamlist = GetCariIdSecici(kurToplamlist,baslangicTarihi,bitisTarihi);//GetCariIdSecici cari idleri bir sp ile çeker ve tüm bu carilerin
                                                    //tüm döviz türleri cinsinden işlemlerinin bakiye toplamlarını hesaplar listede döndürür

            string seperator = " \r\n ";//döviz türleri ile miktarları ikilisinin ayrılacağı string örneğin 100 TL;100 EUR

            var queryBilgiler =
                        from kur in kurToplamlist
                        where kur.KurToplamMiktarGetSet > 0 || kur.KurToplamMiktarGetSet < 0//sadece borcu ya da alacağı olanları çeker
                        join cariBilg in db.TBLP1CARIs// where satırı sayesinde 0USD gibi değerleri almaz
                                      on kur.CariIdGetSet equals cariBilg.ID//FIRMAADI TEL gibi bilgiler için join gerekti
                        select new
                        {
                            cariBilg.ID,
                            HESAPADI = cariBilg.HESAPADI,
                            FIRMAADI = cariBilg.K_FIRMAADI,
                            YETKILIADI = cariBilg.K_YETKILIADI == null ||//yetkili adı nullsa ya da boşsa adı soyadı al aksi takdirde 
                                                                        //yetkili adını al, firma - birey farkı
                                         cariBilg.K_YETKILIADI == "" ?
                                                                        cariBilg.B_ADSOYAD :
                                                                        cariBilg.K_YETKILIADI,
                            FIRMATELEFONU = cariBilg.K_FIRMATELEFON,
                            YETKILITELEFONU = cariBilg.K_YETKILITELEFON,
                            CEPTELEFONU = cariBilg.B_CEPTELEFON,
                            BAKIYELER = String.Concat(kur.KurToplamMiktarGetSet.ToString()+" ", kur.DovizTuruGetSet.ToString())//100 ile TL yi
                                                                                        //birleştirir 100 TL yapar
                        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an expression in the field
`= Fields!col1.Value & " " & Fields!col2.Value`